# Cannot reach spring boot docker container

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose

I am creating a spring boot container but when i reach with postman it gives me 404 not found error.

[image: it starts with 8080 port and also exposes 8080 port]

[image: Docker files]

```
@RestController
public class CategoryController {


    @GetMapping
    public String getCategories(){
        return "RETURNED STRING";
    }
}
```

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.yunus</groupId>
    <artifactId>E-Commerce</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>E-Commerce</name>
    <description>E-Commerce</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My pom.xml file

In my controller i am trying to get the String. It has no relationship with database.

I tried to add a network bridge but it didn't work.
I tried to change datasource url but i don't think it is related to problem.

Comment: Hi Yunus, please include your pom.xml in the question and DockerFile with docker-compose, not in the form of screenshots, so that we can reproduce it on our side. Also, could you please specify how you're building your docker image?

Comment: Your controller doesn't have a dedicated mapping, which it should have. Do something like `@GetMapping("/hello")` and try again. Currently you have no real mapping in there.

Comment: @M.Deinum You don't need to have a dedicated mapping. @GetMapping without parameters corresponds to the default root mapping, which is `http://localhost:8080` in this case

Comment: You didn't in earlier versions but not in newer versions anymore. That changed. At least AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't provided details on your dependencies in pom.xml and how you're building your docker image, it's hard to tell for sure where the issues lie.

Please refer to the project example below. It has a fully working Spring and Docker setup which uses the JIB Maven plugin developed by Google. It doesn't require the creation of the DockerFile, as in your case.

Here's the pom.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-docker-example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start.class>com.example.SpringBootDockerExampleApp</start.class>

        <spring.version>2.5.5</spring.version>
        <docker.platform>1.10.2</docker.platform>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${start.class}</mainClass>
                    <layout>JAR</layout>
                    <classifier>exec</classifier>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>repackage</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <from>
                        <image>openjdk:17-jdk-slim</image>
                    </from>
                    <to>
                        <image>examples/spring-boot-docker-example:${project.version}</image>
                    </to>
                    <container>
                        <mainClass>${start.class}</mainClass>
                        <jvmFlags>
                            <jvmFlag>-Xms512m</jvmFlag>
                            <jvmFlag>-Xmx512m</jvmFlag>
                        </jvmFlags>
                    </container>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The application.yml file for Spring Configurations. I will use the 9090 server port for this example:

```yaml
server:
  port: 9090
```

The main class with a REST controller:

```java
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootDockerExampleApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootDockerExampleApp.class, args);
    }
}

@RestController
class WebController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "Hello Docker World";
    }
}
```

The docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  # application
  spring-boot-docker-example:
      image: 'examples/spring-boot-docker-example:1.0-SNAPSHOT'
      hostname: spring-boot-docker-example
      ports:
      - '9090:9090'
```

You can build the project using the following command:

```bash
mvn clean package jib:dockerBuild
```

And run the docker application with this command:

```bash
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d spring-boot-docker-example
```

After this, you can verify that the application is up and running by executing this cURL:

```bash
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://localhost:9090/
```

If everything is set up correctly, it should return such response:

```bash
test@ip-172-00-0-00 spring-boot-docker-example % curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://localhost:9090/

HTTP/1.1 200 
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 18
Date: Wed, 12 Jul 2023 22:37:33 GMT

Hello Docker World%
```